# How to sync non Amazon books from the iPad Kindle app to a PC or Mac

Tags: kindle, ios

I purchased a Kindle book from a 3rd party publisher on my iPad. I've read it, highlighted it, etc. and really want to transfer it to Amazon Cloud so it is available on my other devices. The "share" option is grayed out on the book.

I'm pretty sure that I can transfer it to Amazon Cloud via the send to device via email option if I can just figure out now to get the ebook off the iPad.

Where are non-Amazon Kindle books stored on the iPad and how can I pull them off or transfer them to another location?

Comment: What type of file is it? mobi?

Comment: Try to use Calibre, I think it will solve the problem

Comment: File type is Kindle, so I think that is mobi, right?

Comment: I had never heard of Calibre, but from the video, it looks very promising. I'll report back later. Thanks!

Comment: My iPad Pro isn't recognized by Calibre. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon went to significant trouble to make it practically impossible to extract a kindle file out of the Kindle app for ios.  (They even make it rather hard -- though not impossible to send files directly to the device app without using the cloud). You can use itunes to add a file into the IOS app (using the "File Sharing" function in itunes; connect the device, select the device --> Summary --> Apps --> (scroll down and select Kindle app and then choose Add file).

Maybe (hopefully) Calibre lets you add files to the ipad. But this is a one way street. Amazon wants to make it impossible for you to have direct access to the ios file system.

But you may appreciate my perspective.

The Kindle app for ios is a truly wretched app for rendering ebooks. As an ebook publisher and formatter, I spend a huge amount of my time trying to make the ebook look less-than-crappy on the Kindle app for ios. (by comparison, It's a breeze to format for Kindle on android or the Kindle devices). Most of my ebooks just look horrible on the kindle for ios. I make a lot of compromises.

The rule of thumb is to try to **use whichever ebook reader  is native to the device**. Ibooks is a best-of-class ebook reading software and certainly the best ebook reading app on ios. If you're buying from a third party (Smashwords?) you should have gotten an epub version and just emailed it and opened it in ibooks. It would look beautiful!

From a practical point of view, I sometimes read purchased ebooks from Amazon on my ipad app. That is unavoidable. But for reading third party stuff on your kindle app, you should be using the  Send-to-Kindle function to get into the cloud, then go to the website and choose the device you want to deliver it to.

Your question is seeking to break through the Kindle app's DRM. Besides being possibly illegal, it also will be technically hard to do. I realize that you probably obtained the ebook file legally. I am unclear what you mean by sharing function.

Perhaps you should log in to the Kindle Personal Documents service via computer, go to **"Manage your content and devices**" , for show, select **Docs**, select the file and click the **Actions** button and then choose **Deliver** from the popup. That's the primary way you share Kindle ebooks across devices.

Finally, a personal recommendation. Even though I have never bought an ebook from the Google Play store, their Play Books app is phenomenal and is the best share-across-devices-and-platforms solution. Works great on ios, Kindles, androids, Windows. They have an easy-to-use interface for uploading epub files to the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. It is funny, I noticed that the book that I received looked pretty crappy on the Kindle, so I also downloaded the PDF version. It really is nicer to read a Kindle edition in the Kindle app than a PDF, though for all the other benefits like highlighting and definitions. So I went back and forth between the two. I've asked the publisher if they'll let me download another copy and then I'll try out Play Books and also send it to my Amazon cloud.